# Maximum Likelihood Formulation for Linear Regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, notation, conditioning

I have seen the following for maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) for linear regression in multiple sources, e.g. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulZW99jsMXY):

$$
\mathcal{D} \equiv \{(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)\}
$$

I do not understand how exactly we derive this:

$$
p(\mathcal{D} | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i | x_i, \theta)
$$

I understand that we can write the product due to the assumtion of independent $y_i$. However, I do not understand why $x_i$ is suddenly on the right side. Shouldn't it be:

$$
p(\mathcal{D} | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i , x_i | \theta)
$$

Comment: I think it depends on what you are trying to model.  In a linear regression you are trying to learn about $y$ from $x$ and thus you need the likelihood to be a function of $y$. In the case of linear regression you are treating $x$ as a quantity that helps you explain the thing you want to learn about, $y$, which is why you treat it as being conditioned upon as if it is fixed and known.

Comment: I understand that we model $p(y|x,\theta)$, however I don't understand why this is equal to $p(\mathcal{D}|\theta)$

Comment: Abuse of notation maybe.

Comment: It's a notational abuse especially often seen in Bayesian contexts in which you have to integrate out the parameters to compute the denominator. You don't need to pay attention to the notation.

Comment: So which part is not correct? Is it wrong to write $p(\mathcal{D}| \theta)$?

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with @DaeyoungLim. 1) This is not an abouse commonly seen in Bayesian statistics and 2) the assertion "You don't need to pay attention to the notation" should never be followed.

Comment: @RustyStatistician Technically speaking, regression makes assumptions. So most of the time, the regressors are given unless you explicitly want to model in which they are treated as random variables. That's why $x_{i}$ are excluded from $D$ and in many cases, they are even omitted. So in a very loose and unprofessional manner, the notation doesn't actually matter. It's the assumptions.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim when someone is asking a question that basically boils down to "hey, I don't understand this notation", the answer of "You don't need to pay attention to the notation" makes no sense.

Comment: @RustyStatistician Touché. I think you're right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ordinary least squares regression the goal is to model the condition expectation;
$$
E[y_i|x_i] = x_i'\beta
$$

$y_i$ and $x_i$ are referred to as the *dependent* and *independent* variables respectively because we are literally conditioning  $y_i$ on $x_i$.

Ordinary least squares is equivalent to maximum likelihood where we assume;
$$
y_i|x_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(x_i'\beta,\sigma^2)
$$
In this instance the $x_i$ are taken as fixed values (we are not calling $x_i$ a random variable and giving it a probability distribution) meaning that the "data", $\mathcal{D}$, is just the set of $y_i$'s
$$\mathcal{D} \equiv \{y_1,..,y_n\}$$

So writing 
$$
p(\mathcal{D} | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i | x_i, \theta)
$$

where $\theta \equiv \{\beta,\sigma\}$ is actually correct.

The likelihood $p(\mathcal{D} | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(y_i , x_i | \theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n p_y(y_i  | x_i, \theta)p_x(x_i|\theta)$ ,on the other hand, treats the $x_i$ as random variables which, although applicable in some settings, is not linear regression in the traditional sense.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. 

Would it be also ok if we still define $\mathcal{D} \equiv \{ (y_1, x_1), ...., (y_n, x_n) \}$, as this is what we actually observe, but further make clear, that $y_i|x_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(x_i'\beta,\sigma^2)$. So that the $y_i$ in $\mathcal{D}$ are samples from a random variable, with associated values $x_i$?

Comment: Technically in this context the answer is no (although this is sort of minutiae).  If we define $\mathcal{D} \equiv \{ (y_1, x_1), ...., (y_n, x_n) \}$ then $P(\mathcal{D} | \theta)$ is a bivariate distrbution and we are required to assign a marginal distribution to $x_i$, $p_x(x_i | \theta)$, which ordinary linear regression is not concerned with (see the last paragraph in the answer).  You could certainty define a likelihood this way (time series and state-space models are a couple great examples) but it is not ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question, would it be possible to write $\mathcal{D} \equiv \{ (y_1 | x_1), ...., (y_n | x_n) \}$?

Comment: It's interesting that you thought about it that way.  I think that notation would technically be acceptable, although it will probably confuse most people.

Comment: You could say that linear regression implies that the given inputs is exactly the distribution of $X$, i.e. $p(x_i) = 1_{x_i \in \mathcal{D}}$